# Creating 302 redirect to a URL that changes dynamically, and passing referring information?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I want to redirect (302) my visitors of `mydomain.com/page.php` to another URL, 
that contains a dynamic value such as the visitor's IP address:

`http://external.com/?ip=100.0.0.1`

my common sense says this cannot be done with `.htaccess`, since the contents of it are static,
and therefore the line would always be something like:

`redirect 302 /redir-number-1 http://external.com/[not-useful-static-value]`

Currently I'm first transferring the user to another PHP page (`mydomain.com/transfer.php`) with this redirection code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;

$url = "http://external.com/?$ip;

header( "refresh:1;url=$url" );
```

But this doesn't seem to consist a 302 redirect, as the status code I get is 200,
and it is also important for me to pass the original referring URL information (`mydomain.com/page.php`) when the visitor arrives to `external.com`, yet with my current method he arrives with `mydomain.com/transfer.php` as the referrer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `.htaccess` in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://external.com/?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I didn't write it in my question, but the IP thing is only one of the strings I would like to have, I'd also want strings that check if or case conditions, that would also come into play in the url, in that case, I guess there's no way to do that with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes, you're right: no way to do that with .htaccess... if you do not explain exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a 302:

`header("Location: $url", true, 302);`

But you are never going to get the correct referrer on a redirect. You need to add it as a variable in the URL maybe.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work actually, though is there a way to have this page make the redirect only after a 1 second pause, similar to my previous code? I do get the correct original referrer to show now, using your method. I would be happy if someone could provide an explanation about how/why it is working now though.

Comment: Sure, just put `, true, 302` on the end of your current header

Comment: If I do that, The Original referrer won't be passed. it would be `mydomain.com/transfer.php`. any other ideas to achieve this?

Comment: Then you're not going to be able to do it with pure PHP. Suggest adding the referrer in the URL if you need it, as above. Not ideal, but the 302 code isn't supposed to be used in this way. It's supposed to tell the browser to retrieve the other url, rather than displaying the contents of the current one.